# Is there a function which takes same elements as input, but gives different outputs for different arrangements?

Tags: functions

Is there a function on a sequence of integers or natural numbers such that when applied collectively to them, gives different result based on the order of subset's element?

Suppose $A$ contains $a,b,c$
And $B$ contains $b,c,a$
Then what is a function such that
$F(A)=X$
$F(B)=Y$ and $X$ not equal to $Y$?

**EDIT**: I believe I have used wrong terminologies and tags, what I meant was function on a, say, sequence of integers.
Where if the arrangements of the elements in that sequence is changed, then the function's output for the sequence changes.

Comment: Sets (without any aditional structure) have no order, so this question makes little sense.

Comment: Apologies for incorrect use of tag and terminology, what I actually meant was something along the lines of a 'sequence' of integers. Is there a function which operates on a sequence and provides different output for different arrangements of the sequence?

Comment: Yea, I think someone has answered that already, but for example you can do $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \to a_1$

Answer (score 0):

Sets are unordered so if $A=\{a,b,c \}$ and $B= \{ b,c,a \}$ then $A=B$. So if by $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ you mean the images of $A$ and $B$ under $f$ then $f(A) = f(B)$.

Comment: Apologies for incorrect use of tag and terminology, what I actually meant was something along the lines of a 'sequence' of integers. Is there a function which operates on a sequence and provides different output for different arrangements of the sequence?

Comment: So something like $f((x,y)) = x^2 + y$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If $$A=\{a,b,c\} $$and
$$B=\{b,c,a\} $$
then 
$$A=B $$
and
$$f (A)=X=f (B)=Y $$

Comment: Apologies for incorrect use of tag and terminology, what I actually meant was something along the lines of a 'sequence' of integers. Is there a function which operates on a sequence and provides different output for different arrangements of the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Now that you ask for a function on sequences of naturals, there are. A simple one is $f((x,y))=2x+y$ The double parenthesis indicates the function takes an ordered pair as the argument instead of two naturals and we have $f((x,y))\neq f((y,x))$